# Method to work out first day of financial year based on year parameter

Tags: c#, .net

Im trying to produce a simple method which can receive a financial year period in the following format:

```
2014-2015
```

I need the method to return a `DateTime` object, specifically the first day of that financial period, in the above case this would be `01/04/2014 00:00:00.000`

I will also need to ultimately be able to work out the last day of that financial period but im not sure whether or not this should be a different method all together or in the same method with an additional parameter to indicate which date is required.

So far all I have been able to come up with is:

```
public static DateTime PermitValidFrom (string financialYear)
{
    string startFinancialYear;
    string endFinancialYear;
    DateTime startOfFinancialYear;

    startFinancialYear = financialYear.Substring(1, 4);
    endFinancialYear = financialYear.Substring(6, 4);

//need to work out start of the financial year based on this period

    return startOfFinancialYear;
}
```

I just don't know how to approach giving startOfFinancialYear a value, or even if there is a better way of going about doing this all together.

Apologies if this has been answered previously, but all I can find is examples which work out the start of a financial year based on the current `DateTime.Now` value, in my case this value may be different every time the method is invoked.

Comment: when does a financial year start? 01/04 no matter what year it is? Some other date?

Comment: Please post the exact definition of what you mean by "financial year", because that differs from country to country.

Comment: Why would the first day of the financial year be 01/04/2014 - that was a Saturday? Shouldn't the first day be 01/01 or 01/02(first non holiday business day of the year)?

Comment: If you format the `startFinancialYear` into the full date you might use the [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: In terms of my application you should assume the first day of the financial year will always be the first of April no matter if this is a Saturday or Sunday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify my question, the facts surrounding my task were the following:

Financial Year Start in this scenario will ALWAYS be 01/04 (the first of April)
Financial Year End in this scenario will ALWAYS be the last day of March.

If this is a Saturday, Sunday or any other day **in this scenario** is irrelevant.

All I have to go on is two years separated by a hyphen, from this I need the start of that financial year and the end of that financial year. I think the facts are pretty straight forward.

Anyway, seen as I received down votes and no real constructive feedback I ended up coming up with my own solution, and thought I would post it in case it helps anyone else.

```
public static DateTime FinancialPeriods(string financialYear, bool end)
{
    string startFinancialYear;
    string endFinancialYear;
    DateTime startOfFinancialYear;
    DateTime endOfFinancialYear;

    startFinancialYear = financialYear.Substring(0, 4);
    endFinancialYear = financialYear.Substring(5, 4);

    startOfFinancialYear = new DateTime(int.Parse(startFinancialYear), 4, 1);
    endOfFinancialYear = new DateTime(int.Parse(endFinancialYear), 4, 1).AddDays(-1);

    if (end == false)
    {
        return startOfFinancialYear;
    }

    else
    {
        return endOfFinancialYear;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would roll your own type, something like this:-

```
    using System;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    public class FinancialPeriod
    {
    const string PATTERN = @"^([0-9]{4})\s?-\s?([0-9]{4})$";

    public FinancialPeriod()
    {
        this.Year = DateTime.Today.Year;

        if (DateTime.Today.Month > 3)
        {
            this.From = new DateTime(Year, 4, 1);
            this.To = new DateTime(Year + 1, 3, DaysInMarch(Year + 1));
        }
        else
        {
            this.From = new DateTime(Year - 1, 4, 1);
            this.To = new DateTime(Year, 3, DaysInMarch(Year));
        }
    }

    public FinancialPeriod(string period) : this()
    {

        Match m = Regex.Match(period, PATTERN);
        this.From = new DateTime(Int32.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value), 4, 1);
        this.To = new DateTime(Int32.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value), 3, DaysInMarch(Int32.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value)));
    }

    private DateTime From { get; set; }
    private DateTime To { get; set; }
    private int Year { get; set; }

    public string period
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} - {1}", this.From.Year, this.To.Year);
        }
    }

    private int DaysInMarch(int yr)
    {
        return DateTime.DaysInMonth(yr, 03);
    }
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wptPjl)